# Как присвоить результаты SQL запроса на выборку переменной?

Tags: delphi, ado

Как присвоить результат запроса на выборку из БД переменной ?

Делаю запрос через компонент TADOQuery:

```
SQLQuery9.SQL.Text := 'SELECT id FROM details ORDER BY `id` DESC limit 1';
b := SQLQuery9; // присваиваю результат переменной
```

-выдаёт ошибку при запуске.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во первых, надо открыть запрос - `SQLQuery9.Open`
получить данные можно через `SQLQuery9.FieldValues['id']`

Полный код:

```
SQLQuery9.SQL.Text := 'SELECT id FROM details ORDER BY `id` DESC limit 1';
SQLQuery9.Open;
b := SQLQuery9.FieldValues['id'];
```

P.S. *В примере нет проверки на наличие результата. Это вне рамок заданного вопроса.*